# Amazon ECS Log File in Fargate

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm migrating from ecs with ec2 to ecs with fargate and have a question In case of ecs with ec2, we emit ECS log like ecs-agent.log, evs-init.log

Are these also available in Fargate? If not, container insight is something similar to these?

Comment: Those are ECS Host logs. Those are not available in Fargate. Is there a specific type of information in those logs that you need for your Fargate deployment?

Answer (score 0):

[Container insight](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/cloudwatch-container-insights.html) allows you to send metrics to cloudwatch like CPU, Memory and more, in order to monitoring your cluster or tasks (in case of fargate) performance.

If you need to save logs from inside your container, for example if you have a Django backend and want to keep those logs, you must set a [LogConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_LogConfiguration.html) in your container definition, for example (using JSON definition):

```
"logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "your-group",
                    "awslogs-region": "group-region",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "container-prefix"
                }
```

In this example you will send the desire log to an Cloudwatch log group named "your-group"